# How to mock an API call with configuration in JEST?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, next.js

I am using `@woocommerce/woocommerce-rest-api` package for my api. I am using NextJS and React Redux. Here is my woocommerce configuration:

```
import WooCommerceRestApi from '@woocommerce/woocommerce-rest-api';

export const wooApi = new WooCommerceRestApi({
   url: 'MY_API_URL',
   consumerKey: 'MY_CONSUMER_KEY',
   consumerSecret: 'MY_CONSUMER_SECRET',
   version: 'wc/v3',
   queryStringAuth: true,
});
```

I dispatch an action right away when the component mounts.

Here's how I use the API in my action:

```
export const fetchMainProductCategories = () => {
    return async (dispatch: Dispatch) => {
       try {
          const response = await wooApi.get(`products/categories?hide_empty=true&parent=0`);
          dispatch<FetchMainProductCategories>({
             type: CategoryTypes.fetchMainProductCategories,
             payload: response.data,
        });

        } catch (error) {
             console.log(error);
        }
      };
   };
```

Here's my initial test statements so far but I doesn't work:

```
import React from 'react';
import '../../__mocks__/matchMedia';
import MockCategories from '../../__mocks__/mockCategories';
import { render, cleanup, logDOM } from '@testing-library/react';
import Index from '../../pages/index';
import Root from '../../Root';
import { wooApi } from '../../config';

jest.mock('../../config');

describe('Homepage', () => {
   beforeEach(() => {
      render(
        <Root>
          <Index />
       </Root>
    );
 });

 afterEach(cleanup);

 it('loads Product Categories', async () => {
       wooApi.get.mockResolvedValueOnce({
          data: MockCategories,
       });
       logDOM();
    // const list = await waitFor(() => screen.getByTestId('category-list'));
    });
 });
```

Comment: What problem do you have with this? You need to mock wooApi.get when you test fetchMainProductCategories, and you need to mock fetchMainProductCategories everywhere else, that's a good strategy for unit testing.

Answer (score 1):

You need to register the `get` method of the `wooApi` as a mock, while preserving the other features of the `api`. ie:

```
import { wooApi } from '../../config'
import { fetchMainProductCategories } from '../where-it-is-defined'

// mark get method as jest mock
jest.mock('../../config', () => ({
   ...jest.requireActual('../../config'), // to avoid overriding other methods/features
   get: jest.fn(), // override get method of the api
}))

describe('Homepage', () => {
   beforeEach(()=>{
      wooApi.get.mockResolvedValue({
         status: 200,
         data: { categories: ['a', 'b'] },
   })

   test('loads ...', async () => {
   const dispatch = jest.fn()

   await fetchMainProductCategories()(dispatch)

   expect(dispatch).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
      { type: '...',
        payload: { categories: ['a', 'b'] }
      }
    )
   })
})
```

**Ref:** 
[Bypassing Module Mocks in Jest](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/bypassing-module-mocks)

Comment: Thanks! I tried this and I got TypeError: _config.wooApi.get.mockResolvedValue is not a function - https://prnt.sc/rzioak

Answer (score 0):

**Edited:** My bad, by doing `jest.spyOn(config.wooApi, 'get')` we are only mocking "get" method of a single instance. The following edited code should work

You can also use `jest.spyOn` to only mock the get method like below

```
import * as config from '../../config'

jest.spyOn(WooCommerceRestApi.prototype, 'get')
WooCommerceRestApi.prototype.get.mockResolvedValue('...')
```

Comment: Yah, I tried this as well and still got the same error. Thank you